# Set weights of stack of layers in Keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I used the Keras model class and have stacks of sequential layers and was wondering how I can access the layers in the stacks to set their weights.

```
class sho_Model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(sho_Model, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_x1 = keras.models.Sequential(layers=[
            Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=7, activation=selu, input_shape=(1, 80, 2)),
            Conv1D(filters=6, kernel_size=7, activation=selu),
            Conv1D(filters=4, kernel_size=5, activation=selu)                              
        ])

        self.hidden_xfc = keras.models.Sequential(layers=[
            Dense(20, activation=selu),
            Dense(20, activation=selu)
        ])
        self.hidden_x2 = keras.models.Sequential(layers=[
            MaxPool1D(pool_size=2),
            Conv1D(filters=4, kernel_size=5, activation=selu),
            Conv1D(filters=4, kernel_size=5, activation=selu),
            Conv1D(filters=4, kernel_size=5, activation=selu),
            Conv1D(filters=4, kernel_size=5, activation=selu),
            Conv1D(filters=4, kernel_size=5, activation=selu),
            Conv1D(filters=4, kernel_size=5, activation=selu),
            AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2),
            Conv1D(filters=2, kernel_size=3, activation=selu),
            AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2),
            Conv1D(filters=2, kernel_size=3, activation=selu),
            AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2)
        ])

        self.hidden_encoded = Flatten()

        self.hidden_embedding = keras.models.Sequential(layers=[ 
            Dense(16, activation=selu),
            Dense(8, activation=selu),
            Dense(4) 
        ])


    def call(self, inputs, n=-1):
        x = K.permute_dimensions(inputs, (2, 1))
        x = self.hidden_x1(x)
        xfc = K.reshape(x, (n, 256))
        xfc = self.hidden_xfc(xfc)
        x = K.reshape(x, (n, 2, 128))
        x = self.hidden_x2(x)
        encoded = self.hidden_encoded(x)
        encoded = K.concatenate((encoded, xfc), 1)
        embedding = self.hidden_embedding(encoded)
        return embedding
```

I have something like

```
curr_layer = 0
for layer in keras_model.layers:
    layer.set_weights(...)
    curr_layer+=1
```

but that just accesses the sequential containers (right term?) and not the individual layers.

Comment: you can access the individual layer from the sequential models with layer.layers

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined those sequential "containers" as separate layers, you could use multi-level for-loop to iterate through individual layers:

```py
curr_layer = 0
for container in keras_model.layers:
    if container.name.startswith('flatten'):
        # Skip the flatten layer
        continue
    for layer in container.layers:
        layer.set_weights(...)
        curr_layer += 1
```

If you want to save and restore weights from previously trained model, an easier way is to use `save` or `save_weights` method to save and restore them with `load_weights` method or [`tf.keras.models.load_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model).